# Could not find a part of the path AjaxMin.dll for AjaxControlToolkit

Tags: visual-studio-2013, ajaxcontroltoolkit, nuget-package

I created a brand new "ASP.NET Web Application" project in VS2013. Then trying to add AjaxControlToolkit from Nuget Package Manager. When I try to install the package I get following error:

**Error**:
Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\Chirag\AppData\Local\Temp\nuget\r25qb1tx.wpx\lib\net20\AjaxMin.dll

[image]

I tried to re-install Nuget package manager but it says its up-to-date. Please help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just realized that I was running VS2013 as normal mode and did not have enough permissions to copy files to target folder. When you "Run As Administrator", I was able to download/install the packages successfully.